# What does this matrix notation mean?

Tags: matrices, notation

What does $|\textbf{M}|$ mean, where $\textbf{M}$ is a matrix? I am under the impression that you can element-wise divide $\textbf{M}$ by $|\textbf{M}|$ to normalize it in some way, kind of like how $|\textbf{v}|$, where $\textbf{v}$ is a vector, means the length of the vector, and by dividing these we get a unit vector.

Comment: If no context is given, determinant, of course!

Comment: I agree with Zhanxiong but we also need the additional condition that $\textbf M$ is a square matrix if we're to think that $|\textbf M|$ denotes determinant of $M$.

Comment: It also may be the norm of a matrix, usually defined as the sum of the absolute value of each entrie in the matrix. Depends on the context. If you're working with ODE's that may be the meaning.